# PHP switch with unknown cases

Tags: php, yii

In a website based on an integer value I need to show text messages to the user. If the website has an integer value that has been not defined in my code, the site breaks.

How can I handle this situation?

My code looks like this:

```
$status = 1;

switch (status) 
{
    case 1:
        status_from_file();
        break;

    case 2:
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Using a [switch default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) maybe?

Comment: You have missed to add your class to the code example. Unless you show the code of the class definition this is hard to understand.

Comment: I wonder how there could be that kind of question, even more, when they are regarding a well known matter of the OP, and he knows what to search for - a `switch` statement. Why the first job of the OP is writing a post in StackOverflow instead of searching `switch` in php.net ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for 'default':

```
 <?php
    switch ($i) {
        case 0:
            echo "i equals 0";
            break;
        case 1:
            echo "i equals 1";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "i equals 2";
            break;
        default:
           echo "i is not equal to 0, 1 or 2";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should check first if its defined and numeric so -

```
    if(isset($status) && is_numeric($status)){

        switch($status){
            //cases here
        }
    }else{
        //status is not defined/NaN
    }
```

if its not defined / not a number it will go to "else" block

Comment: if, switch, else... what more ?

Comment: He mentioned that his code breaks when $status is not defined,witch means its not always defined in his code so he must create an if block to check if its defined other-wise it will throw him an unexpected variable error